# unknown tag c:forEach

Tags: html, jsp, foreach, jstl

I am using a `<c:forEach>.....</c:forEach>` tag in the following .jsp file and receiving `unknown tag c:forEach`. I am using maven and have the following dependency included:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and my simple .jsp file looks as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<h3>Senior Design Project</h3>
<br>
<form action="query" method="post" commandName="queryForm">
    Enter an SQL Query: <br> <br>
    <textarea name="query" path="query" cols="55" rows="3"
        style="overflow: hidden"></textarea>
    <br> <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<br>
<h5>File Paths:</h5>

<c:forEach var="individualPath" items="${paths}">
    <tr>
        <td>${individualPath}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Is there more setup needed for jstl? From what I've read the maven dependency should handle everything. Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the `taglib` at the top of the .jsp page needs to be included as follows:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<body>
<h3>Senior Design Project</h3>
<br>
<form action="query" method="post" commandName="queryForm">
    Enter an SQL Query: <br> <br>
    <textarea name="query" path="query" cols="55" rows="3"
        style="overflow: hidden"></textarea>
    <br> <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<h3>Results:</h3>
<br>
<h5>File Paths:</h5>

<c:forEach var="individualPath" items="${paths}">
    <tr>
        <td>${individualPath}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Even I had this issue, and I resolved it by removing the white space between <%@ and taglib.

Answer (score 0):

do 3 things these will make sure that everything works:

1. add the jstl jar in the build path
2. add the same jstl jar in the lib folder inside WEB-INF
3. Add the tag lib
   '''
   <%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
   '''

Answer (score -1):

```
<%@taglib  uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

Adding this in the top of the jsp file solved the issue.